# type of custom object in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript and I created this object:

```
const initialState = {
    title: {
        value: "",
        error: false
    },
    amount: {
        value: 0,
        error: false
    },
    type: "Food",
    time: new Date()
}
```

I want to use is as initial state of a useState. therefore I want to now what I need to passe as type to my useState.
`const [Form, setForm] = useState< "what should come here?" >(initialState)`;

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface IState {
  title: {
    value: string;
    error: boolean;
  };
  amount: {
    value: number;
    error: boolean;
  };
  type: string;
  time: Date;
}

const [Form, setForm] = useState<IState>(initialState);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
interface SomeName {
    value: string;
    error: boolean;
}

interface IState {
  title: SomeName;
  amount: SomeName;
  type: string;
  time: Date;
}

const initialState: IState = {
    title: {
       value: "",
       error: false
    },
    amount: {
       value: 0,
       error: false
    },
    type: "Food",
    time: new Date()
} 

const [Form, setForm] = useState<IState>(initialState);
```